# What kind of join is JOIN?

Tags: postgresql, join

I was revising the theory of joins in PostgreSQL a bit and I couldn't find the syntax that I usually use:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A A 
JOIN TABLE_B B ON (A.COLUMN_A = B.COLUMN_B) [WHERE ..]
```

What kind of join is this? Is it equivalent with the INNER JOIN?

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A A 
INNER JOIN TABLE_B B ON (A.COLUMN_A = B.COLUMN_B) [WHERE ..]
```

Comment: `join` and `inner join` are the same thing. also depending on what is present in a where clause, a `left|right join` may also be equivalent to an `inner join`

Answer (score 0):

@Haleemur Ali is correct: `JOIN`, by itself and with no "adjective" (e.g. `LEFT`, `NATURAL`, `OUTER`, etc.) is an `INNER JOIN`. I was about to post a question like this myself until I finally found this post, so thanks.

Here's some evidence from [W3Resource](https://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/postgresql-join.php), which I find is a pretty well organized dictionary of Postgres commands:

> If we want to restrict the set of combinations based on some join criteria to determine which rows from both participating tables are considered to return on a match between the columns. Suppose we want to match up the supplier and order Ids. Here is the statement below:

```
select * from supplier join orders on supplier.id=orders.id;

 id |    name    | id | ord_value
----+------------+----+-----------
  1 | Pat        |  1 |      5000
  2 | Kane       |  2 |      8000
```

> or the query can be written like below:

```
select * from supplier inner join orders on supplier.id=orders.id;
 id |    name    | id | ord_value
----+------------+----+-----------
  1 | Pat        |  1 |      5000
  2 | Kane       |  2 |      8000
```

You can also find this in the official PostgreSQL [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM), per Ian W.'s comment below:

> The words `INNER` and `OUTER` are optional in all forms. **`INNER` is the default**; `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, and `FULL` imply an outer join.

(Emphasis added there.) Evidently, what I've called "adjectives" above are actually "qualifiers" in the official lingo; a join like `OUTER JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN` is a **qualified JOIN**. The more you know!

Comment: `The words INNER and OUTER are optional in all forms. INNER is the default; LEFT, RIGHT, and FULL imply an outer join.` SEE **Qualified Joins** under **7.2.1.1. Joined Tables** within  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM

Comment: Thanks Ian, I'll put that in the answer.